# How to get time of calls from android call log and convert it to DateFormat

Tags: android

I am trying to get calls time from call log in android sdk 2.2.

```
        long seconds = cursor.getColumnIndex(Calls.DATE);
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy HH:mm");
        String dateString = formatter.format(new Date(seconds * 1000L));
        destinationTime.setText(dateString);
```

But I am getting the wrong result

```
01-01-70 05:29
```

Can someone point me to the right direction, as what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Anyone have any suggestions for it.

Answer (score 2):

```
 while (Cursor_Call_Logs.moveToNext()) { 
String callDate = Cursor_Call_Logs.getString(Cursor_Call_Logs.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE)); 

long seconds=Long.parseLong(callDate);
             SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy HH:mm");
             String dateString = formatter.format(new Date(seconds));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`getColumnIndex()` - that's the problem, you're getting the column index, not the actual data. It should be something like this:

long dateTimeMs = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex([Calls.DATE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html#DATE)));

Comment: Thanks for answer.But tried it as well not working still getting same output.

Comment: NO LUCK :(  getting following error....................................            java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col -1 failed
 android.database.CursorWindow.getLong_native(Native Method)
 android.database.CursorWindow.getLong(CursorWindow.java:380)
 android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getLong(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:108)
 android.database.CursorWrapper.getLong(CursorWrapper.java:127)

Comment: `long seconds = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(Calls.DATE));`

Comment: @Rishi Can you please check what value `cursor.getColumnIndex(Calls.DATE)` returns and that `cursor` is not empty

Answer (score 1):

Change ur answer to

```
    int secondindex = cursor.getColumnIndex(Calls.DATE);
    long seconds=cursor.getLong(secondindex);
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy HH:mm");
    String dateString = formatter.format(new Date(seconds));
    destinationTime.setText(dateString);
```

First you should use the index to get the value. Index itself is not the value . Second to use the constructor of Date object you should give millis as argument . You converted it to seconds by * 1000L .
It should work fine now .