# Delphi Getting Android call logs date

Tags: android, delphi, calllog

I read with Delphi Android call log. In call log date is such format that Delphi doesn't regognice it. Date is returned like this: "1587377791601".

How can i convert it to format dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss in Delphi?

Comment: Looks like a Unix date/time. Use the UnixToDateTime function from the System.DateUtils unit

Comment: It's the number of *milliseconds* since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.

Comment: Something is wrong, 

CallTime := UnixToDateTime(StrToInt64(DATEx));

Gives result 26.11.52258 03.32.48

Call is made today

Comment: The answer to this SO question will probably help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675077/how-to-get-time-of-calls-from-android-call-log-and-convert-it-to-dateformat

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem. Code is not "optimised" but works:

```
    CallTimeDouble := StrToInt64(DATEx) / 1000; //Gives seconds
    CallTimeDouble := CallTimeDouble / 60; //Gives Minutes
    CallTimeDouble := CallTimeDouble / 60; //Gives hours
    CallTimeDOuble := CallTimeDouble / 24; //Gives dates
    CallTimeDouble := CallTimeDouble + 25569; //01.01.1970 - 30.12.1899
    CallTimeDouble := CallTimeDouble + 0.125; //Added +3h to GMT, Finland

    Result := CACHED_NAMEx + ' ' + NUMBERx + ' ' + FormatDateTime('dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss', CallTimeDouble) + ' ' + DURATIONx;

        ShowMessage(Result);
```